# pthread_create () not creating threads

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

I am working on a multithreaded program but for some reason I can't get my threads to create. When I try debugging it breaks at my pthread_join statements.

```
for (i = 0; i < numThreads; ++i)
{ 
  pthread_create (&(tids[i]), &attr, runnerFunction, &sValue[i]);
}
```

and the join statement is just

```
for (i = 0; i < numThreads; ++i)
{
    pthread_join (tids[i], NULL);
}
```

Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: How about checking the return values of the `pthread` functions?

Comment: try `pthread_create (&tids[i], NULL, runnerFunction, (void*) sValue[i]);`

Comment: @arunmoezhi that is what fixed it. Might I ask why that worked and the pthread_attr didn't?

Comment: if you use `attr` in the `create` call, it should also be used in the `join` call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix the issue

```
pthread_create (&tids[i], NULL, runnerFunction, (void*) sValue[i]);
```

Answer (score 2):

On my machine(suse 11), `pthread_attr_t` is defined like this:

```
typedef union
{
  char __size[__SIZEOF_PTHREAD_ATTR_T];
  long int __align;
} pthread_attr_t;
```

the structure of the attribute type is not exposed on purpose. I guess you just declared a local `pthread_attr_t` object and didn't call `pthread_attr_init(pthread_attr_t *attr)` which initializes the thread attributes object pointed to by attr with default attribute values. So that the value of char arry in the structure is not defined, you used a uninitialized `pthread_attr_t` object when you create the POSIX thread. If you passes `NULL` as the attr argument of `pthread_create()`, so that the thread is created with default attributes.

Answer (score 1):

At least for debugging it is a good idea to always check a system call's return value.

So modify you code like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < numThreads; ++i)
{ 
  int result = pthread_create (&(tids[i]), &attr, runnerFunction, &sValue[i]);
  if (0 != result)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, ("pthread_create() failed with error #%d: '%s'\n", result, strerror(result));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
}
```

This could help finding bugs.

As it seems that your code does not work when passing `attr`, the bug might due to no having initialised `attr` properly.  See [`pthread_att_init()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_attr_destroy.html) for more on how to initialise phtread attributes.